# flutter User class can't be null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm making flutter project, but I search in google everywhere.

Error message:

> The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.

I want to make app go login page if user is null, But I don't know why User class can't be null.

This is my code:

```
class AppState {
  bool loading;
  User user;
  AppState(this.loading, this.user);
}
...
class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  int i = 0;
  final app = AppState(true, null); // Error line

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (app.loading) 
      return _loading();
    if (app.user == null) 
      return _loginPage();

    return _main();
  }

  ...
}
```

searched official documentation about User class in dart and googled my error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare a variable with:

```
User user;
```

This statement tells Flutter that `user` will always have a value that is a valid `User` object. It **cannot** be null.

Then later you call:

```
AppState(true, null);
```

And that means you're trying to assign `null` to `user`, which is not allowed (by your own code).

You will either need to make `user` nullable:

```
User? user;
```

Or you will need to pass a valid `User` object in when you app `AppState`.

Since you seem new to this, I recommend checking out the Flutter/Dart documentation on [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

Because in dart you cannot assing a null value on a var type if you don't declare it.

If you want to have the possibility to assign a null value to user, just declare it like `User? user` , but you have to check if it's null in most cases you'll use user.

So, just add a ? at User, like this

```
class AppState {
  bool loading;
  User? user; <----------added here
  AppState(this.loading, this.user);
}
...
class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  int i = 0;
  final app = AppState(true, null); // Error line

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (app.loading) 
      return _loading();
    if (app.user == null) 
      return _loginPage();

    return _main();
  }

  ...
}
```